# Separate URLs from each other in Notepad++, and put them on their own line

Tags: url, notepad++

I want to do what I've done for the first 30 lines in this picture: [image]

Except I don't want to do it manually, because I have 1838 lines of text.

After this I could easily delete duplicates, and all lines which don't contain URLs,
but right now it's kind of a mess.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, where all links are youtube videos as shown in the screenshot, the following should do:

Search:

```
(.+?)\b(https?://www.youtube.com(?:/watch\?v=\w*)?)\b(.+)
```

Replace:

```
$1\n$2\n$3
```

Don't forget to select the *Regular Expression* Search Mode radio button first.

In case you needed a more generic approach matching *any* URL, the regex could get much [more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url).